# objectForKey crash? iOS

Tags: ios, crash, sigabrt

I am trying to use the following code to load a UIButton and UITextField with information based upon a UISegmentedControl's current segment that is clicked but it is causing a SIGABRT crash.
Here is the code:

```
- (void)updateInfo {

NSLog(@"count1:%d", [self.accounts count]);

[self saveInfo];

NSLog(@"count2:%d", [self.accounts count]);

NSDictionary *dict = [self.accounts objectAtIndex:0];
NSData *imageData = [dict objectForKey:@"ProfileImage"];
UIImage *imageProfile = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
[image1 setImage:imageProfile];

NSDictionary *dict2 = [self.accounts objectAtIndex:1];
NSData *imageData2 = [dict2 objectForKey:@"ProfileImage"];
UIImage *imageProfile2 = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData2];
[image2 setImage:imageProfile2];

if ([self.accounts objectAtIndex:accountSC.selectedSegmentIndex] != nil) {
    NSDictionary *dict = [self.accounts objectAtIndex:accountSC.selectedSegmentIndex];
    //NSString *name = [dict objectForKey:@"Name"];
    NSString *name = [accountSC titleForSegmentAtIndex:accountSC.selectedSegmentIndex];
    [Name setText:name];
    NSData *imageData = [dict objectForKey:@"ProfileImage"];
    UIImage *imageProfile = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    [pictureButton setImage:imageProfile forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else {
    Name.text = nil;
    [pictureButton setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

}
```

The first & second big block of code is temporary because I wanted to see the UIImage's based upon different objectAtIndex numbers.

Here is the console crash log:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2cc08'
```

Any reason why this can be happening? Do I need to post any other code I am using?

I really need help on this, I have been pulling my hair out!!!

Edit1:
I am using this code, also you were talking about isKindOfClass right?
Anyway this is the code:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [self.accounts objectAtIndex:1];
if ([dict isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    NSLog(@"YES");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"NO");
}
```

Im testing now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're sending `objectForKey:` to an `NSString` object, specifically one that you've typed directly into your code somewhere in `@"..."` form rather than one you've created programmatically (or had created programmatically for you). Someone is putting something other than a dictionary into `self.accounts`.

Comment: Yea I am doing that because in my case I need to do something specific. I need to add a object as a dummy in order for my app to work. Then later on I am replacing it with a NSDictionary. How would I mod my code in order to get it to work?

Comment: That question requires more of an overview of your code, since you've obviously got one state transitioning to another and not everyone is aware of the move. However, one solution that works immediately at the local level might be that when you pull the object from `self.accounts`, check its type (e.g. `if([dict isKindOfObject:[NSDictionary class]])`) to see whether the string to dictionary replacement has occurred.

Comment: Also if you need me to post more code, please just let me know.

Comment: Check edit1 in the original post to check if it is the right code to use.
Edit1: I just tested and it prints out NO. 
Edit2: I just added more nslogs for different objectatindex's and the first object in my array is a dictionary (obviously), but the second one is not. So the conversion is not working.
Do you need me to post how I do my replaceObjectAtIndex?

Comment: Probably smart; it sounds like the string is staying in the array somehow.

Answer (score 0):

NSDictionary:   `objectForKey:`

`objectForKey:` returns the value associated with key, or nil if no value is associated with key.

`key`        :A string identifying the value. If nil, just return nil.

(1)you should know the key is not blank

(2)you should know the object is not blank  and the objects are the same type ,because you shouldn't use different kinds of type in a NSDictionary.

e.g.   `{@"key1":NSString,@"key2":NSArray}` //this is a demonstration of error

Comment: ` {@"key1":NSString,@"key2":NSNumber} //this is a demonstration of error ` Should be wrong assumptions